# Visual web gui menu item displays wrong in IE 11

Tags: .net-4.5, internet-explorer-11, visual-web-gui

The project I'm developing for recently switched to .Net4.5 and Visual Web GUI 10.0.4 and a context menu item that works in Firefox doesn't work in IE11 (our official supported' browser).

I can't post images here yet, so here's a link:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7UB.png

notice that the firefox windows has 'invoice together' while the IE window has arrows in a box, and that's it.

Here are all the properites for the menu item:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaHAL.png

The only reference to it in the code is displaying a message box when the 'invoice together' is clicked.

I'm thinking it's an IE display issue, but I'm curious to know if anyone knows a way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same or most probably very similar issue on one of several virtual machines. I have content menu on ListView control. There was no visible menu items' text and there were left and right arrow sliders on the menu.

The web site worked fine on FF, Chrome. Interesting thing was that this context menu problem was not reproduced on other virtual machines with IE11. Only on single one. IE version 11.0.9600.18053 / 11.0.24 (kb3093983) was used on all test machines.

I noticed a slight difference in font's rendering also. Font's size seems smaller.

What I did was applying back IE's default settings and restarting client's machine. This somehow fixed the context menu and font's rendering.

My self explanation is that something in "get font and render it" communication between browser and client OS went wrong. From this came wrong looking menu with sliders.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce fonts size on IE, it would help.